# javafx doesn't load image correctly (rotation)

Tags: javafx

javafx does not load image in the correct rotation after the image is rotated by windows rotate from explorer

reproduce:
1. select a image using windows explorer
2. click the rotate left button
3. load the image using javafx(the below code)
4. the image is loaded but not rotated

is there anything i missing?

```
ImageView iview = new ImageView();
Image image = new Image("/path/to/image");
iview.setImage(image);
```

os: windows10
java version: 1.8

Comment: Are you saving the image after rotating it?

Comment: Those image is auto save after you rotate with windows explorer. anyway Roland gave the answer. and thank you for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX loads the image as it is. However, some images have a rotation flag in the EXIF information which tells the viewing application in which rotation the image is to be displayed. You would have to read the metadata of the image and rotate the image accordingly.

And what ItachiUchiha said, you need to save the image after rotating it.